# datepicker not working with autocomplete symfony

Tags: symfony1, autocomplete, datepicker, symfony-1.4

I am working with a form in symfony in which I need to use both the **autocomplete** and the **datepicker** functionalities. For **autocomplete** I am using `sfExtraWidgetFormInputAutocomplete` and  for **datepicker** I am using `sfWidgetFormDateJQueryUI` in my form `configure()` method. In my form first widget using autocomplete is rendered and then the **datepicker** widget. I have read that there is some compatibility issue with these two.

Please tell me how to make them both work in single form.

Comment: Where do you read that _there is some compatibility issue_ ?

Comment: I think I didnt use the correct word for that. Basically the $ is conflicting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line on the top of the page:

```
jq_add_plugins_by_name(array('autocomplete'));
```